# Is it possible to use an image to edit a mesh to the image's size?

Tags: modeling

I wanna make it so that the mesh i have is cut out in accordance with the transparnt png. So, i have a png with a drawing on it, and a transparent background, is it possible to change the mesh shape so that the background is gone, and the mesh changed shape in a way that its the drawing.

---

Its not possible, but if i have a vector image i can import it as a curve, and then convert it into a mesh

Comment: No, this is not possible with any image. If you have a vector image. you can import that vector graphic as a curve, and then make it a mesh, but this isn't possible in general with a rasterized image.

Comment: Inkscape https://inkscape.org/fr/ could do it, depending on the picture you start from. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R6dgW5J0Osw and you can import to blender after that.

Answer (score 2):

There are two methods I'm thinking of.

The first is using an SVG of the image contour.
Loading the image in Blender Using Import Images As Planes.
Import the SVG.
I converted the SVG to Mesh and applied the same material of the image.

The second try is using the Knife topology tool ( <kbd>K</kbd> ) direct to the imported image to cut the subject. No need for a vector-based program. Delete the unwanted faces.
This method was faster because all is done inside Blender.
Note we have to do short cuts to smooth corners.

[image]

Comment: I use a camera view matched to the image dimension so I can project from view to align correctly. Good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Possible with a lot of thing to do,

First, in order to find the contour of the image, you might want to use OpenCV library to find it.

[image][image]

In newest blender python, it is allowed to use `pip` to get OpenCV package. So it is not that difficult.

Second, you somehow need to let the vector-based mesh in Blender to transform as pixel-based contour data.

If you want to only move the existing mesh vertices without adding any extra vertex, you will need to let the vertices move to the most similar part of the contour. Many method, calculating the description vector will be a good idea.

Or new vertices is fine, then turning contour into vector image will be an good idea. There are a lot of packages that could handle this problem. After that, using those vector
to define new vertices into your mesh and delete(or moving) the original vertices. Also curve is an good option to prevent a lot of unnecessary triangle.